# Replace NA's with a random normal number based on sd and mean of each row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to:

```
    dt <-data.table(V1=c(-1,NA,10),V2=c(-2,3,15),V3=c(NA,5,20),V4=c(NA,NA,NA),V5=c(-3,7,NA),
         avg=c(-2,5,15),stdev=c(.82,1.63,4.08))
```

Which looks like:

```
        V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  avg stdev
    1   -1  -2  NA  NA  -3  -2  0.82
    2   NA  3   5   NA  7   5   1.63
    3   10  15  20  NA  NA  15  4.08
```

I want to replace each NA with a normally distributed random number using the `avg` column for the mean and the `stdev` column for the standard deviation.  For example, in row 1, I want two random numbers (to replace NA's in `V3`,`V4`) calculated using mean=-2 and sd=0.82.  In row 2, I want two random numbers (to replace NA's in `V1`,`V4`) calculated using mean=5 and sd=1.63, etc.  Same logic for all rows.  I tried this and it didn't work as expected:

```
    for (col in colnames(dt)) dt[is.na(get(col)), (col) := rnorm(1,mean=(avg),sd=(stdev))]
```

I welcome any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Please, explain why your code does not work as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.

```
library(data.table)

dt <-data.table(V1=c(-1,NA,10),V2=c(-2,3,15),V3=c(NA,5,20),V4=c(NA,NA,NA),V5=c(-3,7,NA),
                avg=c(-2,5,15),stdev=c(.82,1.63,4.08))

# change V4 to numeric, otherwise is logical
dt[, V4 := as.numeric(V4)]

set.seed(1234)
for (col in names(dt)[1:5]){
    # rnorm() is more annoying than expected, n = 1 cannot recycle
    dt[is.na(get(col)), (col) := as.numeric(rnorm(rep(1, sum(is.na(get(col)))), avg, stdev))]
}

#           V1 V2        V3        V4       V5 avg stdev
# 1: -1.000000 -2 -1.772508 -1.110758 -3.00000  -2  0.82
# 2:  3.032483  3  5.000000  1.176513  7.00000   5  1.63
# 3: 10.000000 15 20.000000 16.750829 17.06471  15  4.08
```

Comment: Thanks so much for figuring this out @GL_Li.  I greatly appreciate your help.  It really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to presume that there isn't anything special about `avg` and `stdev` columns and that they are just rowwise means and standard deviations.

First a helper imputation function

```
impute <- function(x) {
  avg <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  stdev <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  indices <- which(is.na(x))
  x[indices] <- rnorm(length(indices), avg, stdev)
  x
}
```

Next strip out the `avg` and `stdev` columns.

```
no_avg <- dt[, !(colnames(dt) %in% c("avg", "stdev"))]
```

Then apply the `impute` rowwise. `data.table` and `t` just get us back to the original format.

```
data.table(t(apply(no_avg, 1, impute)))
```

Comment: Note that if a row is entirely `NA`, `impute` will return a vector of `NaN`.

Comment: this works well.  Thanks so much for the help.  I am going with @ GL_Li 's answer as his is so close to my current solution.